# how to write maximize over multiple conditions

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

All,

I know how to write an equation if I am maximizing over one condition. For example,

```
$\max_{0 \leq x \leq 1} f(x)$
```

But I an not sure how to write it if I have to maximize the function over two conditions and I would like the second condition to appear below the first condition. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: are you referring to "\substack" ?? It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 25):

You can use `\substack`, provided by the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \max_{0 \leq x \leq 1} f(x)
\]

\[
  \max_{\substack{0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ a \geq y \geq b}} f(x)
\]
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[image: Substack as limits]

It works similar to an `array` where multiple lines are separated using `\\`. Another alternative would be to use the `\mathop` - it produces the same result as above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \mathop{\max_{0 \leq x \leq 1}}_{a \geq y \geq b} f(x)
\]
\end{document}​
```

`\mathop` makes it's argument an operator, which allows for the traditional limit placement using `_` and/or `^` which adds it below/above the operator.