# How to write maximize/minimize over condition in inline math mode

Tags: amsmath

I'd like know how to write max/min over condition in inline math mode (i.e. $...$). So far I found only the way to write it in the [equation block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342538/how-to-write-underneath-max-in-formula-latex) (i.e. begin{equation}.....end{equation}) and in the [display math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31507/how-to-write-maximize-over-multiple-conditions) (i.e. \[....\]).

Comment: Have you tried `$\max\limits_{<condition>} <expression whose value is to be maximized>$`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution @Mico it works very well

Answer (score 1):

A solution is:

```
$\underset{k}{\max}$
```